# @ FocusedBinding behavior change on macOS 12

Tags: macos, swiftui

The following code works as expected on macOS 11, but doesn't work on macOS 12. Specifically, on macOS 12, View -> Show Inspector doesn't change the value of `showInspector` in the document. Is this a regression in SwiftUI? Do I need to update the code for macOS 12?

On macOS 12, `showInspector` is `nil` so the menu item doesn't do anything.

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ShowInspectorBinding: FocusedValueKey {
    public typealias Value = Binding<Bool>
}

extension FocusedValues {
    var showInspectorBinding: ShowInspectorBinding.Value? {
        get { self[ShowInspectorBinding.self] }
        set { self[ShowInspectorBinding.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ShowInspectorCommand: View {

    @FocusedBinding(\.showInspectorBinding) var showInspector

    var body: some View {
        Button( (showInspector ?? false) ? "Hide Inspector" : "Show Inspector") {
            showInspector?.toggle()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct CommandTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: CommandTestDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(after: .sidebar) {
                ShowInspectorCommand()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: CommandTestDocument

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            if document.showInspector {
                Text("Inspector")
            }
        }
            .focusedValue(\.showInspectorBinding, $document.showInspector)
    }
}

extension UTType {
    static var exampleText: UTType {
        UTType(importedAs: "com.example.plain-text")
    }
}

struct CommandTestDocument: FileDocument {
    var text: String
    var showInspector = false

    init(text: String = "Hello, world!") {
        self.text = text
    }

    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.exampleText] }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        text = string
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
        return .init(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}
```

(Note: that's the entire code. You should be able to just copy it into a project)